# How to rearrange rows by index range in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this's a very basic question, but I could not find the answer in Google. 
I have a dataset started from 8am and I want to rearrange the dataset to let it starts from other time.

A example dateset is like this:

```
df = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
```

I want to rearrange the data to make it like from `index 9->14` and then `index 0->8`.

How could I get it?

**Desired output:**

```
10
11
12
13
14
15
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do that but `df[9:].append(df[:9])` or `df[9:].append(df[:9]).reset_index(drop=True)` would do I guess.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, sorry for the confusion. I updated the post.

Comment: @Kevin, how should it look like for `pd.Series(np.arange(31))`? Your goal is not clear...

Comment: @JohnGalt, thank you! This is what I want. I recorded the data started from 8am and I want to rearrange the dataset to let it starts from other time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.concat((df[9:], df[:9]))
Out: 
9     10
10    11
11    12
12    13
13    14
14    15
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
dtype: int64
```

Replace 9 with your cutpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate indices:

```
print (np.r_[9:len(df.index), 0:9])
[ 9 10 11 12 13 14  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]

print (df.reindex(np.r_[9:len(df.index), 0:9]))
9     10
10    11
11    12
12    13
13    14
14    15
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
dtype: int64
```

Also working:

```
print (df.loc[np.r_[9:len(df.index), 0:9]])
9     10
10    11
11    12
12    13
13    14
14    15
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `iloc`.

```
df.iloc[list(range(10, 15)) + list(range(0, 10))]

10    11
11    12
12    13
13    14
14    15
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
9     10
dtype: int64
```